# Tick labels appearing twice

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure that is a dendrogram on top of a scatterplot, where the ends of the leaves on the dendrogram match up with the dots on the scatterplot, which in turn match up with the tick labels below. I have this working, but for some reason the tick labels appear twice. The labels in red and green are the ones I'm trying to keep.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import numpy as np
import json
import random

def scatter_and_dendrogram(df, colors,wn='',label_x=False):
    '''Args:
            df (Pandas DataFrame): similarity matrix
            colors (list of strs): list of colors
            wn (str): window name
            label_x=False(Bool): whether or not to label x axis
        Returns: None
    '''
    norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
    dist_matrix = [] #linkage
    for i in range(len(df)):
        arr = []
        for j in range(1,len(df.iloc[i])):
            arr.append(df.iloc[i,j])
        dist_matrix.append(list(arr))
    X = np.asarray(dist_matrix)
    Z = sch.linkage(X, 'ward')
    sch.set_link_color_palette(['b'])
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='col', sharey='row',
                         gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1],
                           'height_ratios': [30, 1],
                        'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})
    (ax1, ax2) = axs
    dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(Z=Z, p=3,ax=ax1)
    icoords = dendrogram['icoord']
    dcoords = dendrogram['dcoord']
    lst = [[],[],colors]
    for i in range(len(icoords)):
        ic = icoords[i]
        dc = dcoords[i]
        if dc.count(0) == 2:
            lst[0].append(ic[0])
            lst[0].append(ic[-1])
        elif dc.count(0) == 1:
            ind = dc.index(0)
            lst[0].append(ic[ind])
    lst[1] = [-0.1]*len(lst[0])
    ax2.scatter(lst[0],lst[1],s=10,norm=norm, alpha=0.7)
    fig.canvas.set_window_title(wn)
    ax1.set_yticklabels([])
    ax1.set_xticklabels([])
    ax2.set_yticklabels([])
    ax2.set_xticklabels([])
    if label_x:
        letters = list('ABCD') 
        labels = [letters[ind] for ind in dendrogram['leaves']]
        c1 = '#ff0033' #red
        c2 =  '#006600'#green
        xlbls = ax2.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=11,linespacing=3)
        for lbl in xlbls:
            t = lbl.get_text()
            c = c2
            if letters.index(t) < 2:
                c = c1
            print(c)
            lbl.set_color(c)
    ax1.set_title(wn)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Aggregation Criterion',fontsize=15)
    ax2.set_xlabel('Articles', fontsize=15)
    plt.show()


l = ['A','B','C','D']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=l, columns=l)
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
        r = random.randint(0, 10)
        df.iloc[i,j] = r
        df.iloc[j, i] = r
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
print(df)
wn = 'Set C'
scatter_and_dendrogram(df, l, wn,True)
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) about `sharex` and `sharey`

> When subplots have a shared x-axis along a column, only the x tick
> labels of the bottom subplot are created.
>
> Similarly, when subplots have a shared y-axis along a row, only the y tick labels of the first column subplot are created.
>
> To later turn other subplots' ticklabels on, use [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

You need to add `ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=False)` under `xlbls = ax2.set_xticklabels`.

Besides, if `fig = plt.figure()` is useless, remove it.